# Volley loads response two times?

Tags: java, android, caching, android-volley, response

Using a few online tutorial i was able to do a simple app that uses volley to get a file form a server, and im saving into cache the file, everything seems to be working fine,

the only problem that I have is that my data get readed two times, my guess is that one is form the original response and the other one 
from the cache. It is posible to only read the cache file if theres no intenet? or how can I prevent the app from reading the data twice.

on my log I see:

Response: -> all the data from the response

and again I see

Response: - > all the data from the response

```
private  void infoo(String u, String p) { 
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject(data);

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, params,  new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("collection"); 
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        getting data from response here
                    }
                     My adapter is here

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                try {
                    Cache.Entry cacheEntry = HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response);
                    if (cacheEntry == null) {
                        cacheEntry = new Cache.Entry();
                    }
                    final long cacheHitButRefreshed = 3 * 60 * 1000; // in 3 minutes cache will be hit, but also refreshed on background
                    final long cacheExpired = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // in 24 hours this cache entry expires completely
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    final long softExpire = now + cacheHitButRefreshed;
                    final long ttl = now + cacheExpired;
                    cacheEntry.data = response.data;
                    cacheEntry.softTtl = softExpire;
                    cacheEntry.ttl = ttl;
                    String headerValue;
                    headerValue = response.headers.get("Date");
                    if (headerValue != null) {
                        cacheEntry.serverDate = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
                    }
                    headerValue = response.headers.get("Last-Modified");
                    if (headerValue != null) {
                        cacheEntry.lastModified = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
                    }
                    cacheEntry.responseHeaders = response.headers;
                    final String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                            HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                    return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString), cacheEntry);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | JSONException e) {
                    return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
                super.deliverResponse(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
                super.deliverError(error);
            }

            @Override
            protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
                return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
            }
        };

        myrequest.add(request);

    }
```